# Is it possible to specify a java.util.log formatter via a -D option or some way that doesn't require a code change?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I have a java program which is using the default XML logging as no formatter is defined, I am wondering if there is a way to change this outside of modifying the code or adding a logging.properties file(it has none atm). Is there a way to specify/change the default file handler from XML to SimpleFormatter for Java.util.log? It's logging configuration is hard coded:

```
fh = new FileHandler("/path/to/logfile",true);
logger.addHandler(fh);
```

Rather then having to add fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter()) in the code here, I am wondering if there is anyway via command line that I can specify SimpleFormatter to be used as the default formatter rather then the XML formatter which it defaults to?

Thanks for any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify how logging should be done in several ways, and they are all described in the javadoc for [LogManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).

You can set the system property `java.util.logging.config.file` and use a file for configuration, or you can set `java.util.logging.config.class` and use a class to configure the logging.

The `logging.properties` file in the `JRE/lib` directory will be used if none of those properties are set (unless the code specifies another logging configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can set the system property `java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter` according to the [Java Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html).